# How do I get the css selector of p:autocomplete element?

Tags: css, primefaces

How would be css selector of p:autocomplete element, inside a html renderized table, like that?

```
<p:dataTable id="tabelaItens" value="#{cadastroPedidoBean.itens}" var="item">
    <p:column headerText="SKU" style="text-align: center; width: 100px">
        <p:inputText size="8" />
    </p:column>

    <p:column headerText="Produto">
        <p:autoComplete id="autocomplete" />
    </p:column>
```

Comment: There is no 'the' css selector. And in this case it might also depend on what comes before it. Use a browser developer tool and inspect the client-side generated html and deduce what csz selector suites you . Plain and (rather) simple

Comment: Solved. The problem was related to the PF version. In older versions than 5.X, the nested class didn't must have the property setted.

Ex: < 5.x
    .myClass input {
      prop: value;
    }

Ex: >= 6.x
    .myClass input {
      prop: value !important;
    }

.myClass {
  prop: value !important;
}

Comment: using !important is not the right choice. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8768317/how-do-i-override-default-primefaces-css-with-custom-styles

Comment: And what you descibe of 'solved' is for me totally unclear how it is related to the question. Either improve the question and create a real answer or remove the question.

Comment: Or better to you, clear your answer kuketje!

Comment: And go master PF!

Comment: 'clear my answer'??? And thanks for acknowledging I'm a master in PF...

Comment: Kukeltje was trying to help but you are convinced using `!important` is the right way to override PF CSS... It almost never is.